# Website with one login

Tags: php, mysql, security, authentication

If i'm making a website with only one login (an admin) would it be safer (i feel like it's easier) to just store the username and password as a variable in the document, rather than having it in a mysql table?

If i just stored it as a variable, i wouldn't have to salt or crypt it would i?

I'd be making a session no matter what.

Comment: Rather take the time, do proper encryption and save the username and password to the database. Don't be lazy now :) It will be safer and the work will be done, so if you want to add other users later on you can do so without having to rework your entire application. Of course it all depends on your application requirements, if this is a simple application used only by yourself to track the number of times you go to the toilet, go ahead, save the password in a file unencrypted, what do we care :)

Comment: @user65439 How will it be safer in a database, compared with _encrypted in a variable_? What are the security pros of _database storage alone_?

Comment: Why not simply use .htpasswd then or restrict to IP

Comment: @geomagas I believe Artur already answered your question below.

Comment: @user65439 Did he now?

Comment: I think saving user and password in php is equally secure. Would be nice to salt and encode password so you save in file only username, salt and hashed password. This way even if someone see this file, they still dont know password. PS. Why you even need username if there will be only one user? :)

Comment: @Volvox one minor detail though: You don't even have to store a username. We have (user)names to be distinguished from others. Since there'll be only one admin, storing only _the_ hashed password should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store passwords literally in your PHP code. Here is why:

Imagine you are installing APAche+PHP on your server - it mayu look like this:

- install Apache
- ohh...it is done - so I'll put my php code into htdocs
- install PHP

After step #2 everyone using Apache can read your php **source code** as it cannot be yet passed to php for parsing.

Same situation may happen if your PHP/apache installation is malfunctioning - you show your code (with passwords) to everyone.

To be funnier requests to your site may be cached in some proxy and even if you later make your apache+php work correctly your source code with passwords are still there.

If you do not want to use a database - store password in a file (but use a DB) which would be outside htdocs directory (or /var/html/www) whatever so that it cannot be accessed by apache directly.

As for storing password itself - store it's hash and when validating compare hash of what whoever provides with a hash that you have - no need to store password literaly.

**Update:**:
As for storing username+pass for DB access in your PHP code - it's ok. Just assign this user appropriate rights on DB site so that this particular user can access appropriate resources (and best read only) from only your site. This way for whoever gets these they will be useless for him. It all depends on specific situation...so treat it as rough hints or list of things that you should be aware of.

**Update #2 - better read this:**

I'll not delete what I wrote above - but I admit it is clumzy - written very fast and I have not conveyed what I intended too clear.
Her is what you may really do and will be fine for you. Suppose you have index.php file where you would normaly perform all operations - validate user pass, access db. So you kind of want to keep all this info in this file. Due to issues mentioned above it may be seen by unauthorized people sometimes.

Do this (fast and working):

- in the same directory where your 'index.php' is create 'private' subdir
- in 'private' put 2 files '.htaccess' and 'secret.php':

**index.php**

```
<?php    
    require_once('./private/secret.php'); // defines ADMIN_HASH, DB_USER, DB_PASS
    // here you can use ADMIN_HASH, DB_USER, DB_PASS and
    // even if someone gains access to the source code from
    // this file (via HTTP) no one will see your priv data
?>
```

**/private/.htaccess**

```
deny from all
```

**private/secret.php**

```
<?php
    // define here any private data that you wish
    // file will be included from others but never allowed to be seen due to rewrite rule from .htaccess
    define('ADMIN_HASH', 'your admin password\'s hash - for example md5');
    define('DB_USER', 'user used to access db');
    define('DB_PASS', 'password for above user');
?>
```

Of course mod_rewrite must be working on your Apache. Above prevents you from keeping private data directly within your code that may be visible if PHP not working. At the same time even if PHP is not working (and code cisible) still nobody can access your 'private/secret.php' file using http.

Comment: Then where should I store my passes for the DB?

Answer (score 0):

A password hardcoded in the source code is only available to the people having access to the source code. So yes, it's prone to less exploits.

Moreover, since there will be only one admin password, storing it somewhere else would be an overkill by itself.

However, salting/crypting is another matter. You could store it encrypted, still in a variable, if there are concerns of other, not-so-trusted people having access to the source code (or should the source be compromized due to other security holes of the system).